# Do we have to have a real bank account for paypal developer's account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am new to paypal and a bit of confused about its types of account and their rules and functionalities. A lot of questions came to my mind while going through those accounts and I searched for them but couldn't get a clear answer on these
1.What is the difference between personal business and developer's account?
2.Do we have to have a real bank account for paypal developer's account?
3.If it is so, then does paypal charges even for developer's account ?
4.If not can we get fake credit from paypal itself just for testing purpose?
and finally 5.where do a developer finally login to access the REST API which the paypal provides?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Paypal terms of use, and not programming.

Comment: Michael, PayPal is directing people here now for general PayPal developer questions.  It sort of goes against the rules for SO, but it's tough to knock people for it when the PayPal developer site sends them here to get things like this answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Not a whole lot.  In most cases people use Personal accounts in the sandbox as payer accounts, and use business accounts for seller accounts.  You need a business account setup for things like Payment Pro, Payments Advanced, etc.

2)  No, when you create your developer sandbox accounts they will get setup with a fake bank account and credit card number.

3)  No, any transactions made in the sandbox are completely fake, but it does allow you to complete transactions all the way through so you can see the entire flow, and then also see what it looks like in each user's PayPal account.

4)  Answered in #3.

5)  Not exactly sure what you're asking here.  Just login to http://developer.paypal.com and go into the Documentation section.  Everything you need is in there.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for making this so clear..I have signed up for paypal developer account and by default its business acount.But I cannot verify my account.Paypal sent me a mail with a link to verify my mail but when i follow the link it asks my password but after it gives an error:The confirmation number you have entered does not match our records for this account. Please check the number and try again.I've copied the number i got in the mail but still I cannot verify my mail.I am stuck with this

Comment: For the account used to login on developer.paypal.com: no, you do not need a real bank account.